# .NetCore Querying - Joining Many-to-Many Tables And Returning Result and Including a Key With Array of Strings

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

Please, I’m having some challenges working with many to many relationship when working with .netCore . 
I have this case; a user can belong to many departments and a department can have many users. Initially, I had some challenges implementing the many to many relationships. But after much research, I was able to get a solution. Now, joining the tables to get all users that has Administration as part of their department. I'm a bit confused on how to get the users department(s) into its own array when querying

Here is my classes so far

```
// User Class
    public class User
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }     
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }       
        public virtual ICollection<UserDepartment> UserDepartments { get; set; }
    }

// Department Class

public class Department
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserDepartment> UserDepartments { get; set; }
}

// UserDepartment Class (Intermediary Table)

public class UserDepartment
{
    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public Department Department { get; set; }
}
```

This is my desire output;

```
[
{
    "userId": 1,
    "fName": "John",
    "lName": "Doe",
    "depts": ["Administration"]
},
{
    "userId": 2,
    "fName": "Simon",
    "lName": "Simpson",
    "depts": ["Administration", "Support"]
},

]
```

And here is my own try of the query

```
  public async Task<IEnumerable<object>> Test()
  {
        var result = await _context.Users
             .Select(p => new
             {
                 UserId = p.Id,
                 FName = p.FirstName,
                 LName = p.LastName,
                 Depts = //TODO - To fix getting user depts p.UserDepartments.Any(d => d.Department.DepartmentName == "Administration")
             }).ToListAsync();

        return result;

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now, joining the tables to get all users that has Administration as
>   part of their department.

Try with:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<object>> Test()
  {
        var result = await _context.Users
             .Select(user => new
             {
                  User = user, 
                  Departments = user.UserDepartments.Select(userDepartment => userDepartment.Department.DepartmentName)
             })
             .Where(tuple=> tuple.Departments.Contains("Administration"))
             .Select(tuple=> new
             {
                 UserId = tuple.User.Id,
                 FName = tuple.User.FirstName,
                 LName = tuple.User.LastName,
                 Depts = tuple.Departments
             }).ToListAsync();

        return result;

  }
```

Another approach would be to find the matching department entity and from then on access its associated users through the nav. properties:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<object>> Test()
  {
        var adminDep = await _context.Departments
               .Include(dep => dep.UserDepartments)
               .ThenInclude(userDep => userDep.User.UserDepartments)
               .SingleOrDefaultAsync(dep => dep.DepartmentName == "Administration");
        if(adminDep == null) throw new InvalidOperationException();
        var result = adminDep.UserDepartments
                .Select(userDep => userDep.User)
                .Select(user => new
                {
                   UserId = User.Id,
                   FName = user .FirstName,
                   LName = user .LastName,
                   Depts = user.UserDepartments.Select(userDep => userDep.Department.DepartmentName)
                 }).ToList();

        return result;

  }
```

Comment: @Jota.....This works like charm. Many thanks for the help. Just to confirm best practise, is it a good idea i return this data as an object as it is from the repository end and then map to a DTo on the controller end.........OR , i map to a class in repository then return and finally map to a DTo at the controller end?? . What is the best strategy?

Comment: Repository should "emulate" a collection of domain models (eg: entity classes) in memory, so only domain models go in and out of it. (eg: `UserRepository: IRepository<User>`). The mapping should most definitely not be done at that level. Neither at controller level, ideally a controller should be a thin layer that forwards requests into a form of API/Businnes/Service layer, where also mapping from domain models into DTOs or similar should take place.

Comment: ...So, basically, if i can get you right.....On the Domain layer, return data as an entity(class). Then on the controller level, request from outside should be map from DTo to domain entity and when returning to the outside, map from entity to DTo??

Comment: No, controller should map input into a form of DTO and pass it into the API/Business layer, which is defined by the last. Your last statement is correct, but the domain -> DTO mapping should only take place at API/Business layer, ideally.

Comment: Take https://github.com/zkavtaskin/Domain-Driven-Design-Example as example.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the include method provided in the .net core to fix getting user depts,just like this:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<object>> Test()
{
    var result = await _context.Users.Include(s => s.UserDepartments).ThenInclude(n => n.Department).Select(p => new 
    {
            UserId = p.Id,
            FName = p.FirstName,
            LName = p.LastName,
            Depts = p.UserDepartments.Select(s=>s.Department).Select(k => k.DepartmentName)

    }).ToListAsync();        
    return result;
}
```

Comment: @Tao....Many thanks for the feedback. I just tried this now....but there is no way I can use the ThenInclude(x=> x.Department). This is not accessible at this place even after including the UserDepartments on the first line of the query.

Comment: @GNG What do you mean by `This is not accessible `? Do you use EF Core?

Comment: Yes, i'm using EF Core. What i meant is that after including the UserDepartments, when i use the =>  ThenInclude(n => n.Department), i couldnt do that on the query as this throws an error.

Comment: @GNG What error did you get? Is there any demo to reproduce your issue. I am wondering why you got error with `ThenInclude` in ef core.